# Why was TrueCrypt Discontinued

Tags: truecrypt

I know this happened a long time ago, but I always wanted to ask this to a professional: Why was TrueCrypt Discontinued?

Is it related to this: [FBI hackers fail to crack TrueCrypt](http://www.techworld.com/news/security/fbi-hackers-fail-to-crack-truecrypt-3228701/)?

And what is the best option, **without backdoors**, currently available?

Comment: Answer from a professional (albeit not for crypto): We just don't know.